# How to get a scrollbar in Colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to prepare a functionality for uploading images. I'm using color box for the same thing. When an administrator presses a button a colorbox appears with an option of image uploading.

Apart from this I have additional functionality that displays the images which has been uploaded. I have given 100% width and height to the colorbox. The problem is that it is possible to view only certain number of images on the colorbox. Because there is no scroll bar in colorbox the administrator can't view more than 10 images.

So for this problem I need a colorbox with scroll functionality so that he can view all images which he has uploaded in the previous occasions n current occasions as well.

My code for color box..

```
var colorbox_wallpaper = {
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%",
        iframe: true,
        reposition:true,
        scalePhotos:true,
        scrolling:false,
        previous:'<i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>',
        next:'<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>',
        close:'&times;',
        current:'{current} of {total}',
        maxWidth:'100%',
        maxHeight:'100%',
        onOpen:function(){
            document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        },
        onClosed:function(){
            document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
        },
        onComplete: function(){

        }
    };
```

Comment: Please structurize your question a little more and provide code examples and what you already have tried, it's difficult to help the way it is

Comment: Did you try to set scrolling to "true"?

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to set this in your css for that element

overflow:scroll;

cant explain unless you give some example code. what have you tried?